# How to use Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll to get the site information the page is running on?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have a half dozen sites on my server and I would like to get some info from IIS7 to display in the footer of each page (as long as you are an admin of course).  I am going through the ServerObject and found Sites but am not finding anything obvious for "this site".  ***What should I do to get at the information for the exact site in IIS7 that the page is running on?***

For a quick 'hack' style approach I wrote this on my default.aspx page code behind:

```
ServerManager serverMgr = new ServerManager();
foreach (Site site in serverMgr.Sites)
{
    string s = info.Text + site.Name + @"<br/>";
    info.Text = s;
    foreach (Binding binding in site.Bindings)
    {
        string t = info.Text + binding.BindingInformation + " | ";
        string p = t + binding.Protocol + @"<br/>";
        info.Text = p;
    }
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are after to get some simple information about the current website, there are some great methods such as `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName()` or `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteID()` and so on. Otherwise, the following code snippet may be helps.

```
using (ServerManager sm = new ServerManager())
{
    foreach (Binding b in sm.Sites[HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName()].Bindings)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```