# How to get site's URL using ServerManager object

Tags: c#, iis-7

I am trying to get site's URL here but not able to figure out how to get it,

```
using (var mgr = new ServerManager())
{
    foreach (var site in mgr.Sites)
    {
        var siteURL = site. ??
```

Here's class I am using

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.application.virtualdirectories(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I know nothing of IIS so I might be off in space but did you see this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/3027525/2145211

Comment: Try site.Attributes["Url"] It's a guess by the way. But there is an attributes member of 'Site' that exposes values such as the name etc. Url might be in there!?

Comment: @DeeMac its not possible

Answer (score 1):

Umm..I guess this might help..

```
ServerManager serverMgr = new ServerManager();
Site site = serverMgr.Sites["YourSiteName"];
List<string[]> urls = new List<string[]>();
foreach (Binding binding in site.Bindings)
{
    string bindingInfo = binding.BindingInformation;
    string subString = bindingInfo.Substring(2, bindingInfo.Length - 2);
    string[] adrs = subString.Split(':');
    adrs[0] = "localhost:" + adrs[0];
    urls.Add(adrs);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sites is a Sitecollection and you can get sites by looping through its items.

If you are just looking for website's url why dont you use Request object.